# memcpy doesn't seem to copy the correct data

Tags: arrays, pointers, struct, memcpy

I'm trying tio copy a string of ipv6 address from one variable into another one but I get the wrong value, I have this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef unsigned char bcm_ip6_t[16];

int main (void){

typedef struct {
        bcm_ip6_t IPv6addr;
        }mytype_t;

        bcm_ip6_t outarr;

/****************/

        mytype_t myvar[64];

        strcpy(outarr,"001122334455667788");

        printf("outarr %s\n",outarr);

        memcpy(myvar[0].IPv6addr, outarr, 16);

        printf("0x%x TEST0\n0x%x TEST1\n", myvar[0].IPv6addr[0], myvar[0].IPv6addr[1]);

return 0;
}
```

and I would expect to see following output:

```
outarr 001122334455667788
0x00 TEST0
0x11 TEST1
```

but I'm seeing this:

```
outarr 001122334455667788
0x30 TEST0
0x30 TEST1
```

why is this and how can I fix that?

Thanks,
Ron

Answer (score 1):

You are printing ASCII values of the characters, not the binary values of the address bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You copied a string into an array of unsigned chars.

You then printed out the hex values of the unsigned char array.

The character '0' is represented by the hex value 0x30 - that's why you saw it twice.